# ruby - how to find library dependencies for spawned subprocess

Tags: ruby, bundler

Let's say I've got Ruby process A using a set of dependencies managed by bundler.

I want to spawn a subprocess and have that subprocess do work in a separate set of dependencies.

Specifically:

- process A accepts incoming API requests to run an automated test suite
- process A spawns process B
- process B runs the test suite using a separate set of tools & dependencies

Currently when I spawn B, I'm getting errors like this:

```
/Users/foomanchu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable cucumber for gem cucumber. cucumber is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

Thoughts ?? Thanks ~~

Comment: Is `cucumber` in your Gemfile? How does process A spawn process B?

Comment: using backticks currently. Might explore other options. Someone pointed out some of the bundler docs here --> https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bundler/bundler/Bundler.unbundled_system which is sort of the opposite solution. But maybe something in Bundler gets me what I'm looking for.